# Custom 500 error page for only one template

Tags: django, django-views

Hi i cant figure out how i can create a custom 500 page but only for a single view, i basically want to redirect to another template when i get an 404 error by not passing a positional argument.

i currently made an .html custom page, but its works for any page.

im triying to do something like this:

```
def handler_no_board(request,exception): 
    board= request.GET["board_id"]
    if board == null
       return render(request,'board-not-found.html')
```

Comment: Just render it in that specific view by rendering a template for a 500, and alter the status code to 500 (or some code between 500 and 599).

Answer (score 0):

Use `if board == None:` to check if the variable existed or not.